# Explain the logic in this math equation

Tags: square-numbers

$$
n = 4^x
\\
n = 2^x \times 2^x
\\
\sqrt n = 2^x
\\
\log_2\sqrt n = x 
$$

I do not understand how $$ n = 2^x \times 2^x $$ is transformed into $$ \sqrt n = 2^x $$

Square root is undone by raising something to the 2nd power. But they somehow managed to undo it.

Please ELI5.

Thank you.

Comment: What does "raising something to the 2nd power" mean to you?

Comment: To @Jessica: what is $x^2$ for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is behind transforming the number $4$.

Basically, the original equation can be rewritten as follows:

$$
n = 4^x \\
n = (2^2)^x
$$

Using the properties of exponents, we can rewrite $(2^2)^x$ as $(2^x)^2$. Then, taking the square root of both sides, we get:

$$
n = (2^x)^2 \\
\sqrt{n} = 2^x
$$

Another way to think about it is: that in the second step of your original process, $n$ is equal to $2^x \cdot 2^x$. Anything multiplied by itself is that thing squared, so $2^x \cdot 2^x = (2^x)^2$. Now, we can take the square root again:

$$
n = (2^x)^2 \\
\sqrt{n} = 2^x
$$

Comment: Thank you very much for explaining it like this. This answer you provided makes the most sense to my brain. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Let $u=2^x$. The step you are confused about becomes $n=u*u=u^2 \implies \sqrt{n}=u$ For positive $u$, this is true. Like you said, the square root is the inverse function to squaring.